# opshub visual studio team services (was visual studio online) azure authentication 2 factor / app possible?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

The VSTS account (target for migration) uses an Azure authentication mechanism via an app, not simple user password.

Is this possible with the OpsHub migration utility today or what are the work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. OpsHub Migration Utility re-uses the same end point which you create in Visual Studio. It does not store any credential information in itself. So, this will work as expected.